# How can I tell if I window is receiving input (not showing a modal dialog, etc)

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I'll let my application be automated from another application by exposing a net pipe. Basically, application B will emulate being a user using application A, which is a WinForms application.

My only problem so far is that I don't want application B to be able to access functionality you wouldn't be able to access if you'd be an actual user, like clicking buttons in a form while there is a message box or a modal dialog on top of it. This should keep me on the safe side while still giving application B full control over application A.

What I would do is override `MessageBox.Show` with custom code, as well as every call to any `ShowDialog` in application A to set some global boolean to false while the modal dialog is being shown that will tell whether the main form is accessible at the moment or not. Then I could either make application B wait or return an error.

But instead of my solution, is there some built in way to tell whether a form has a dialog on top or not? I tried 'Active', 'Focused', even the native `GetForegroundWindow` but none of them work as I need. To start with, all of them will be false if my application is minimized, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal dialogs disable their owners so one simple test would be to check if the window was enabled. Use IsWindowEnabled to determine this. You also need to check that the window is visible with IsWindowVisible.

Comment: I tried this. I'm almost sure it was still enabled but I'll try again just to be sure.

Comment: OK tried again. Is always `Enable` even with a dialog on top. This is what I do in case I'm missing something: `Text = Enabled.ToString() + new String('.', dots);`. This happens inside a timer which increments `int dots` every second to make sure is still being called.

Comment: OK so I _was_ missing something. I'll give that a try.

Comment: That works for dialogs but not for menus. Somehow Windows must know the difference since if you move your mouse over a button in the form while a menu is open, the button won't do its typical highlight.

Comment: But yea this is officially the right answer since I didn't mention menus in my question. But any clue how to do this with menus as well?

Comment: Menus are indeed very different from top-level windows. But I don't see where they come into your question. What exactly do you want to do with menus?

Comment: Well while a menu is open, user won't be able to click buttons in a form, so while a menu is open I should do the same as when a dialog is on top (prevent my other application from accessing functionality you would access by clicking buttons as a real user). Many of these menus will dynamically add or remove or disable buttons when the menu is open, and the application assumes nothing else will change in the App while the menu is open.

Comment: Why would a menu being open stop buttons from being clickable?

Comment: Well you can click buttons but the menu will close right away. You can't click buttons _while_ the menu is open. For instance, I usually build my menus dynamically when it opens with a list of items, and assume these items won't change while the menu is open since to change it it would need to click other buttons which would also close the menu.

Comment: Yes you can. Open notepad. Open the file menu. Click on the notepad icon (the system icon at the top left of the caption bar). Or open explorer. Right click in the main part of the window and then click the New Folder button. Then menu closes *and* the button is pressed.